# Get value from anywhere in a text file

Tags: c#, linq

I have a value "md5: [md5 value here]", that appears half way across a line roughly 15 lines into a text file.

IE:

```
File was uploaded successfully, md5: [md5_value_would_be_here]
```

I have no control over the txt files contents so cant write the value to a new line, then pull it.

In c# how would I go about getting the value of md5: (I know in batch I could use a find and replace, but completely blanked out on how to do it in c#).

Any help appreciated :)

heres what I'm using so far...

```
var data = File
                .ReadAllLines("file.txt")
                .Select(x => x.Split('='))
                .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
                .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);

string serverFileMD5 = data["md5"];
```

Thanks

Update:

The following doesn't reach success,

```
String data = File.ReadAllText("File.txt");
            String pattern = "md5: ([a-zA-Z0-9]*) ";
            Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
            Match m = reg.Match(data);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                Group g = m.Groups[1]; // This should be the hash
                Console.WriteLine("value of g: " + g);
                serverFileMD5 = g.Value;
            }
```

Comment: And what is the problem with that code? An example of your file could be really usefull here.

Comment: The example you provided doesn't contain a single `=`, yet that's what you are using to split the lines.

Comment: Why put the `()` in the regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is by using Regex. Firstly I'd probably read the entire file into a single string:

`String content = File.ReadAllText()`

Then you can use something along the following lines:

```
String pattern = "md5: \[([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\]";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
Match m = reg.Match(content);
if(m.Success) {
    Group g = m.Groups[1]; // This should be the hash
    String hash = g.Value;
}
```

This makes the assumption that you're hash contains uppercase characters, lowercase characters and numbers. It works like this:

`md5:` - literally looks for `md5:` to start the matching

`\[` - looks for an open bracket, the `\` is used for escaping

`(...)` - creates a matching group, the bit that matches in here will be in `m.Groups[1]` making it easier to access the result.

`[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - This is the long way to say match any alphabet character or number. Note that the `*` means match many of these, without this it'd just pickup the first character.

`\]` - simply look for a close bracket, again being escaped

If you need more information about Regex to help you modify the capture, I'd simply recommend checking out a cheat sheet such as [Regexlib.com](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: Thanks for this! However, what would the regex be if the brackets were spaces? \s?

Comment: @user2295457 the square brackets `[` and `]`? Simply swap them out with spaces in the pattern. Spaces are treated literally as spaces, in fact you can see that at the `md5: \[` which features a space in it. The `(` and `)` brackets need to be in there to create the Regex matching group, these are special characters and it **won't** look for those in the original string so you can ignore them.

Comment: Ok so got it, was the regex (notepad++ wasn't showing some characters in the file, checking with regular notepad reviealed no starting space char, and an = trailing... Just need to trim 4 characters from the left now (the "md5:") in my output string and I'm good! Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to find a single MD5 hash of length 32, which always follows the text `md5:` (including the space), this simple solution should suffice:

```
var data = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\somewhere\DummyTextWithHash.txt");
var lineWithMd5 = data.First(line => line.Contains("md5: "));
var md5StartPos = lineWithMd5.IndexOf("md5:").Dump();
var md5Value = lineWithMd5.Substring(md5StartPos + 5, 32);
```

This is fairly explicit, and should hopefully be entirely self-explanatory.

One thing to note though: `data.First(...)` may throw an exception if no MD5 value is found in the file (typically *`Sequence contains no matching element..`*). If you're not sure if there will always be an MD5 in the file, use `FirstOrDefault()` there instead, and check if it returns anything before trying to extract the value (it will return `null` if no match was found).